# Lim of 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Please help with this:

Let 
$$f(z,b) = \begin{cases} z\sin(1/b), & b \ne 0, \\ 0, & b=0. \end{cases} $$

I'm trying to calculate the limit $f(z,b)$ for $(z,b)$ approach to $0$, in order to check if $f$ is continuously at $(0,0)$.

Please help with this way if is the right way...

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: since $0 \le | \sin ( \cdot )| \le 1$, $|z \sin(1/b)| \le |z| \to 0$.

Comment: Since |z| is bigger than  zsin (.) Is mean that multiply of 2 number that one of them approach to 0 and second is lower that first give me lim kind of 0*0=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since |z| is bigger than  |zsin (.)| Is mean that multiply of 2 number that one of them approach to 0 and second is lower that first give me lim kind of 0*0 ?